# meaning of the phrase "as to" in context?

Tags: meaning

The sentence with the phrase that puzzles me is from the journal [Psychology Today](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/friendship-20/201712/8-tips-dealing-someone-you-cant-stand?utm_source=FacebookPost&utm_medium=FBPost&utm_campaign=FBPost) Here it goes:

> Data has long shown that predictability and control (link is external) can lessen our physical stress response and our associated feelings of upset. Without being so rigid **as to** set yourself up to be thrown off if things don't go exactly as planned, come up with a specific strategy that outlines what your interaction will be like.

What does *as to* mean there? I feel that the word *as* might be redundant there. Could you please rephrase the whole sentence with the phrase for me?

Comment: It's part of the construction ***so** [adjective] **as to** [unmarked infinitive verb]*, which in something like *He's so mean as to save and re-use clingfilm* is equivalent to *He's so mean **that he saves and re-uses** clingfilm*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Without being so rigid as to [verb phrase]

This is part of a formulaic comparator, one that is used with a verb phrase. Another way of saying the same thing would be:

> Without being so rigid that you [verb phrase]

as in

> Without being so rigid that you set yourself up to be thrown off if things don't go exactly as planned ...

Here it is in a simpler sentence:

> Don't eat so much as to give yourself indigestion.
>   Don't eat so much that you give yourself indigestion.

Etc.